SQLC panic: unable to mmap memory: cannot allocate memory
I was using SQLC on Ubuntu virtual machine from one provider and it was working perfectly fine, but then I switched to another provider and all of a sudden it now panics with panic: unable to mmap memory: cannot allocate memory.
I discovered that this panic only occurs when SQLC binary installed using go install, but it doesn't if I reinstall SQLC using snap.
Code and SQLC configs don't change between both machines, their specs are identical with 2 cores and 4 RAM, so it can't be that machine running out of memory.
What can cause the panic?
You can see full trace on pastebin: pastebin

I have the same problem when running sqlc vet in my dockerfile.

The problem seems to be with the newest version of SQLC (v1.26.0).
When installing via go install github.com/sqlc-dev/sqlc/cmd/sqlc@v1.25.0 this doesn't happen to me anymore.

sqlc installed via snap is v1.26.0 and it doesn't cause the issue
